# CSS Affecting inner elements

Tags: css

I have a font awesome arrow icon inside a link tag. On mouse hover,I want the arrow to move slightly to the right like this:       http://mo-de.com/#contacts
My css :

```
 a:hover{
  transform:translateX(2px);
 }
```

But it moves the whole link. How can I access the specific tag I want or the icon to move it independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the id to the fa-icon example id="icon" and then have pseudo class as

```
#a:hover ~ #icon {
     transform: translateX(2px); 
}
```

This will work

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: I want when I hover over my button,the arrow inside it moves and not the whole button.
In your code,I'll have to hover over the arrow